# Package com.esri.arcgisruntime.ogc.kml for Arcgis API of Java

Tags: java, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

I am currently working on a project where I have to convert my data into kml. So, I go through this java package `com.esri.arcgisruntime.ogc.kml` on the developers website of ESRI.

This package basically provides interfaces and classes for working with Keyhole Markup Language (KML). KML is an XML-based data format that defines a range of geographic data structures such as placemarks, descriptions, ground overlays, paths, and polygons.

With this packages we  can:

- Determines how altitude values should be interpreted.
- Defines a KML color mode.
- The list of KML list item types.
- The list of KML geometry types.
- KML node refresh statuses.
- The list of KML graphic types.
- KML refresh modes.
- KML tour execution status.
- A KML units type.
- The list of view types.
- List of KML view refresh modes.

Now, I need some working example or reference of this package, so that I can modify my java project accordingly because on the ESRI website , only details of the package are there and there is no such working example that how this package works.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java sample code](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/) page and search for KML at the top of the Table of Contents.

Comment: but there is no pratical example there, just a dictionary refrence

Comment: That link is gold, if you follow the instructions you can reach [KML](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/create-and-save-kml-file/) and the [full runnable project](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-java/tree/main/kml/create-and-save-kml-file).

Answer (score 0):

That library looks good, I reached the same conclusions, but this lib is quite complex, it needs 480 MBs of native code extracted to specific location(s) (see copyNatives in the [example project](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-java/tree/main/kml/create-and-save-kml-file)) to execute this code:

```kotlin
val kmlDocument = KmlDocument()
// Call .get() to make sure it's synchronously saved.
kmlDocument.saveAsAsync(File("test.kmz").absolutePath).get()
```

additionally

- it needs a custom maven repository reference (mavenCentral is not enough)
- it might also need a licence

I also looked at other libraries:

- [This API from Nasa](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/gov/nasa/worldwind/ogc/kml/package-summary.html) also looked promising, but it's only reading KML files; additionally it's a ZIP, not distributed on mavenCentral().
- [Java API for KML](https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml) which actually works, here's an [example](https://github.com/usc-isi-i2/Web-Karma/blob/master/karma-commands/commands-import/import-spatial/src/main/java/edu/isi/karma/geospatial/WorksheetGeospatialContent.java#L332).